# How to use domains to handle exception in node js app

Tags: node.js, error-handling

In my node js app i want to catch the exception using domains.How can i do this.I have tried the below example but it showing error as 'Error: Cannot find module 'step''..

app.js

```
            var domain=require('domain');
            var mainDomain = domain.create();
            mainDomain.run(function() {
            fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', mainDomain.intercept(function(data) {
               console.log(data);      
            }));               
             });
            mainDomain.on("error", function(error){
               console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: If that's the error you're getting, I don't think you're showing the full script. There's a [step library](https://github.com/creationix/step) but it's not being called in the code you show.

Comment: @robertklep i haven't installed step library.using domain i want to catch the errors.

Comment: The code above works just fine, so you're not showing the full code.

Comment: @robertklep Above is my full code i have just tried the above code from this link snmaynard.com/2012/12/21/node-error-handling/...

Comment: Here's a fully functional demo: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5393914

Comment: @robertklep i have tried that example but i'm getting error while running that code.I have mentioned that error clearly in github.

Comment: It looks like you might have another module called `domain` installed. Try removing `var domain = require('domain')` from the demo code.

Comment: @robertklep ok but again it will show domain not defined error while using that domain in this line 'var mainDomain = domain.create();'

Comment: It won't if you use Node 0.10. If you're using an older version of Node, you're going to have to rearrange your code to prevent another `domain.js` from taking precedence over the built-in `domain` module.

Comment: @robertklep ok im using node 0.6.17 thats y i'm getting error i think.

Comment: Oh that could very well be. I believe domains require at least Node 0.8

Comment: @robertklep ok i will update my node to new version.thanks for ur post..

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you solved this back in April. However, just to complete your post, I just had the same issue.

The error is thrown on the line:

```
var domain=require('domain');
```

The problem was to do with running earlier version of Nodejs. I installed the latest version (v0.10.21) and the problem is resolved.